# Why do these equivalent statements have different solution sets?

Tags: inequality

I am unfortunately unable to work out this very simple problem: Why is it that two equivalent inequalities have different truth/solution sets?

Given $\sqrt{2x+3} > x$, we have 
$$\sqrt{2x+3} > x \iff 2x + 3 > x^2$$ 
$$\iff x^2 -2x - 3 < 0$$
$$ \iff (x-3)(x+1)<0$$

The natural domain for the original inequality is $[-1.5,\infty)$
. The solution set for the last expression for the inequality is $(-1,3)$.

My assumption was that for any logically equivalent statements, the truth sets for the statements are equal. Here I am a bit baffled because the truth set for $\sqrt{2x+3}>x$ is $[-1.5,3)$, but $-1.5$, for example, fails to be a solution for $(x-3)(x+1)<0$, i.e. $-1.5$ cannot be in the truth set for that open sentence.

Shouldn't $\{x:\sqrt{2x+3}>x\} = \{x:(x-3)(x+1)<0\}$, since the predicates are equivalent? Have I made a mistake in assuming the forms are actually equivalent?

Edit: I am wondering if this could be an issue of domain for $x$, but I don't see how since the solution of the latter inequality is a subset of the valid values of $x$

Comment: This equivalence is wrong $\sqrt{2x+3} > x \iff 2x + 3 > x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring can lead to extraneous solutions. For example, the equation $x=1$ has solution set $\{x:x=1\}$, but squaring the equation gives $x^2=1$ which has solution set $\{x:x=\pm 1\}$.

In a similar way, squaring your original inequality does not give an equivalent inequality. In particular, if $a<b$ then $a^2<b^2$ when $a,b\geq 0$. However, this is not necessarily true if $a<0$ or $b<0$ (e.g. $-2<-1$ but $(-2)^2=4>1=(-1)^2$). So in your case, you should treat $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* true that$$\sqrt{2x+3}>x\iff2x+3>x^2.\tag1$$The inequality $\sqrt{2x+3}>x$ automatically holds if $x\leqslant0$ (and only makes sense if $x>-\frac32$). If $x\geqslant0$ then, yes, $(1)$ holds.